# _base.py:251: FutureWarning: Support for multi-dimensional indexing - WHAT?

Tags: python, deprecated

I have a project with a couple thousand lines of code.

I'm getting this message when it runs:

> (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.   y = y[:, np.newaxis]

The error message doesn't give me any line number to go look at and I have no idea what to look for to try to debug this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The warning comes from line number 251 in _base.py ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to run Python with `-Werror`, i.e

```
python3 -Werror myproj.py
```

This will cause Python to exit with a full traceback when the warning is triggered.

The same effect can be achieved by setting the [`PYTHONWARNINGS`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS) environment variable to `error`.

Comment: No so helpful answer for others trying to fix this specific FutureWarning.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when using Python's matplotlib.pyplot library, where I **converted the input data** from the plot() function **to numpy Array**, such a warning is not availabled, just for reference.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30450534)